# If $\gcd (a,n) = 1$, how can we prove that $\gcd(a + kn, n) = 1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

If $\gcd (a,n) = 1$, then how can we prove that $\gcd(a + kn, n) = 1$, where $k$ is any integer?

I feel like I should start with linear combinations theorem, but I'm quite lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $au+nv=1\iff (a+kn)u+n(v-ku)=1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If some prime $p|n$, $p|a+kn$, then $p|kn$ and...

Comment: I think the next step would be to prove that p <= 1, though how would that help in the context of the problem?

Comment: Of course, as $p$ is prime, $p \geq 2$.

Comment: again, how does that help, sorry for the constant questions, still trying to understand the theory

Comment: We are saying that if there exists a prime $p$ such that $p|n$, and $p|a+kn$, then this prime must also divide $a$. But remember the hypothesis that$ \gcd(a,n)=1$. I am using a proof by contradiction here.

Comment: Does that help?

Comment: sort of, though i am still a bit lost, but it's my own fault, thank you for your help!